# iFrame content inside Modal, goes to quirks mode on mobile only, therefore it does not display

Tags: lightning-aura-components, mobile, iframe

some help on this would be really appreciated please!

I have a lightning component in which a modal is shown on a button click. Inside an iFrame I display a SF Attachment file (CommSiteURL + /servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file= + ID), no matter what the content of the iframe is anyhow, on Desktop it displays fine. But when on mobile view, the content does not get displayed. It removes the `<!DOCTYPE html>` of the iframe content, which I believe might have something to do with it.

The VF page has doctype declared as html 5.

Any workaround or solution on this please?
Thank you very much in advance!

```
<section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01" aria-modal="true" aria-describedby="modal-content-id-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
<div class="slds-modal__container">
   <header class="slds-modal__header">
     <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:close"
       onclick="{! c.closeModal }"
       alternativeText="close"
       variant="bare-inverse"
       class="slds-modal__close"/>
     <h4 id="modal-heading-01" class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-hyphenate">{!v.attachmentName}</h4>
   </header>
   <div class="slds-modal__content slds-scrollable_none" id="modal-content-id-1">
     <iframe class="iFrame" aura:id="iFrame" frameborder="0" src="{!v.viewAttachmentURL}" style="width:100%;height:100%;"/>
   </div>
   <footer class="slds-modal__footer">
     <div class="slds-align_absolute-center">
       <lightning:button variant="neutral"
          label="Close"
          title="Close"
          onclick="{! c.closeModal }"/>
      </div>
    </footer>
</div>
</section>


<aura:attribute name="viewAttachmentURL" type="String"/>

component.set("v.viewAttachmentURL",CommunitySiteURL+"/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file="+attachment.Id);
```

Comment: Would it be possible that you provide key parts of your markup? It would facilitate answering your question.

Comment: @FelixvanHove I have added the related code, thanks!